# Having trouble with python object name and input string

Tags: python, class

I am having a problem with python classes and string I would like to name a class object using a string given from raw_input I don't even now if this is possible.this is how I tried to did it but the code didn't work. I searched in many posts on stackoverflow.com but none of these was answered; I am a neofite of Python, I know how classes and instance works but I don't know any function that help me to fix this problem.

```
class example:
    def _init_(self ,name):
        self.name=name
        input1 = raw_input("")

input1 = example()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not recommending that you do this, but one way to do it is with [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement):

```
class Example:
    pass

name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
exec('{} = Example()'.format(name))
```

Assuming that the user entered "abcd" at the prompt, an instance of class `Example` would be bound to a variable named "abcd":

```
>>> abcd
<__main__.Example instance at 0x7f841fb45908>
```

There is rarely any genuine reason to do this,  and I do not recommend this approach because `exec()` can execute arbitrary user input, creating a serious security issue.

Another way is to update the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary:

```
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
globals()[name] = Example()
```

but this is probably not the best thing to do either, and there is usually a better way depending on what you are trying to achieve.

A safer way could be to use a dictionary with user's input used as the key:

```
user_vars = {}
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
user_vars[name] = Example()

>>> user_vars['abcd']
<__main__.Example instance at 0x7f841fb45908>
```